# Normal transcendental extension

Tags: field-theory

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_extension), normal extension are assumed to be algebraic. But one of the definitions

> $K/k$ is normal if any $k$-embedding $\sigma : K \rightarrow \Omega$ of $K$ into a fixed algebraic closure $\Omega$ of $K$ does not leave $K$ i.e. $\sigma(K) = K$

is applies perfectly to any field. What happens to transcendental extension $K/k$ that satisfies this property? Are they all essentially algebraically closed?

**EDIT**: Thanks to @Joanpemo, I realize that I made a mistake in the definition of *normal extension*: $\Omega$ is supposed to be algebraic closure of the smaller field $k$, not of $K$. Nevertheless, the question is still applicable: We can still ask for transcendental extension $K/k$ satisfying my wrong definition.

Comment: I doubt that a transcendental extension can be embedded into an *algebraic* one ...

Comment: @Joanpemo Since $\Omega$ is algebraic closure of $K$, it should be possible to embed $K$ into $\Omega$. For instance, take $k = \mathbb{Q}$, $K = \mathbb{R}$ and say $\Omega = \mathbb{C}$ as algebraic closure of $\mathbb{R}$. But of course, in $\mathbb{C}$, we can "move" $\mathbb{R}$ while fixing $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: As far as I know an *algebraic closure* of a field is an **algebraic extension** which is algebraically closed. Perhaps you're confusing with field algebraically closed?

Comment: @Joanpemo Well, $\Omega/K$ is algebraic by definition of algebraic closure but $K/k$ might well be transcendental as in my previous comment. I edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: But again: how do you expect to *embed* a transcendental extension  of $\;k\;$ into an **algebraic closure** of $\;k\;$ ?! If $\;\alpha\in K\;$ is transcendental, then $\;\sigma(k)\in\Omega\;$ would have to be algebraic over $\;k\;$ ...doesn't sound right, does it?

Comment: Oh, now I see! You have a mistake in your definition of "normal": $\;K/k\;$ is normal if every embedding $\;K\to\Omega\;,\;\;\Omega$ an alg. closure **of the field** $\;k\;$ , *not* $\;K\;$...and which contains $\;K\;$ . So definitely $\;K/k\;$ cannot be transcendental